# How to use AndroidStudio sample resources?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

As presented on Google I/O 2017, the AndroidStudio has now a sample resources type that can reference JSON files (useful to preview lists with different elements on each position).

[image]

How do I configure my project to use this new resource? I've attempted to reproduce the code, but it doesn't compile.

[image]

The video that presents this new resource is available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hx_rwS1NTiI&t=6m48s

Comment: Trying to do the same thing here xD

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Comment: Not yet. I'll let you know if I find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know when this feature was released, but after updating my AndroidStudio to version 3.1 Canary 8 and creating a new project from scratch, it worked for me!

[image]
[image]